# Drupal module_invoke() and i18n

Tags: drupal, internationalization

I am tasked with i18n-ing our current CMS setup in Drupal. 
The problem that I am facing is with use of module_invoke() to place blocks within nodes.

I have managed to string translate blocks, and that is working when a block is placed in a region (block content is successfully translated) using the UI.

However, when a block is injected into a node like such:

```
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', 22); print $block['content'];
```

It is not getting translated, or even worse, not showing at all.

I have also tried this variation using t(). e.g.:

```
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', 22); print t($block['content']);
```

to no avail.

Generally speaking I've having a bit of trouble with blocks for i18n. Does anyone have a recommended approach for dealing with blocks in drupal with regards to translating them? I would prefer not to create different blocks for each language.

Comment: Also: does anyone know if language can be passed to module_invote. e.g.: $block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', 22, 'en')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So .. After digging around in the bowels of Drupal - and much hair pulling .. I've come up with an almost decent solution.

Basically, with this function, I can extract a translated version of a block:

```
function render_i18n_block($block_id, $region = "hidden"){

    if ($list = block_list($region)) {
        foreach ($list as $key => $block) {
          // $key == <i>module</i>_<i>delta</i>
          $key_str = "block_".$block_id;
          if ($key_str == $key){
          return theme('block', $block);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in my node, I simple call:

```
<?php echo render_i18n_block(<block_id>,<region>); ?>
```

There can be some issues where your blocks might not be displaying in a region (and therefore you can't pass a region into block_list). For this case, I simply created a region called "hidden" which is not rendered anywhere in my template, but can be used to call block_list.

Finally (and this is the part that I still need to find a good solution for), I discovered that block_list() in: includes/blocks/block.inc has a bit of an issue.

It appears that $theme_key is not reliably set unless block_list() is being called from the theme() function (in includes/themes.inc) .. this causes the SQL to return an empty results set. The SQL looks like this:

```
$result = db_query(db_rewrite_sql("SELECT DISTINCT b.* FROM {blocks} b LEFT JOIN {blocks_roles} r ON b.module = r.module AND b.delta = r.delta WHERE b.theme = '%s' AND b.status = 1 AND (r.rid IN (". db_placeholders($rids) .") OR r.rid IS NULL) ORDER BY b.region, b.weight, b.module", 'b', 'bid'), array_merge(array($theme_key), $rids));
```

As you can see, if theme_key is not set, then it will just return an empty result. 
For now I am bypassing this by simply adding:

```
if (!isset($theme_key)){$theme_key="<my_theme_name>";}
```

in modules/blocks/block.inc::block_list() around line 429 .. I still need to work out a better way to do this.

- 10 for anyone with suggestions on how I could ensure that $theme_key is set before calling block_list :)

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem as you, since I was using

```
  $block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 'block_id');
  print render($block['content']);
```

to inject the block into my nodes. However, looking up [module_invoke](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7) in the Drupal reference, I found a comment titled "to render blocks in Drupal 7 better to use Block API", with this code:

```
  function block_render($module, $block_id) {
    $block = block_load($module, $block_id);
    $block_content = _block_render_blocks(array($block));
    $build = _block_get_renderable_array($block_content);
    $block_rendered = drupal_render($build);
    return $block_rendered;
  }
```

I just un-functioned it to use directly, like so:

```
  $block = block_load('block', 'block_id');
  $block_content = _block_render_blocks(array($block));
  $build = _block_get_renderable_array($block_content);
  print render($build);
```

And for me it works like a charm. Be aware however that this method prints the block title as well, so maybe you'll want to set it to 'none' in the original language.

Comment: Thank you! Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function like this

```
<?php

function stg_allcontent2($allC, $level
= "1") {

    global $language;   $lang = $language->language;

    foreach ($allC as $acKey => $ac) {

        if($ac['link']['options']['langcode']
== $lang){          if ($level == "1") 
                $toR .= "";

            if (is_array($ac['below']))
                $class="expanded";          else
                $class="leaf";
                            $toR .= "<li class=\"".$class."\">" . l($ac['link']['link_title'], $ac['link']['link_path']) . "</li>";

            if ($level != "1") $toR .= "";          if (is_array($ac['below'])) $toR .= "<ul class=\"menu\">".stg_allcontent2($ac['below'], "2")."</ul>";           if ($level == "1") $toR .= "";      }
    }
    return $toR; } ?>
```

call like this

```
<?php echo '<ul class="menu">'; echo stg_allcontent2(menu_tree_all_data($menu_name
= 'menu-header', $item = NULL)); echo '</ul>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:  http://drupal-translation.com/content/translating-block-contents#

UPDATE: the t() function allows you to pass in the language code to use.

Comment: Thanks patic. I've been through that, and *seem* to have got it working with string localization (at least to the extent that - as far as i can tell - when a block is dropped into a region using the Drupal UI it is being translated. 

The problem is that even though the strings are theoretically localized, when i render the blocks using code (as above), the language is not being applied to the rendered code :(